# Loopback js mongdb Null or Missing Fields

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback js for backend rest api. I'm switching from Mysql to Mongodb.

I have been using query filters like these:

```
{filter:{where:{fieldName:null}}}
```

This works fine with mysql but when switching to mongodb it dosen't work.
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/  It is supported as document says. Am I missing some configurations for loopback?

My goal is to change mysql to mongodb without updating any queries.

Answer (score 2):

The connector is turning your query into `command=find [ { fieldName: { '$type': 10 } },`

You can add this to your datasource object to use the extended operators and regain your functionality.

`"allowExtendedOperators": true`

ex
`{ "where": { "or": [ { "name": null }, {"name": { "exists": false } } ] } }`

Comment: With this solution I need to still update my queries for api. No I just want to switch the database without updating queries.

Comment: I agree it's a suboptimal solution, but a cursory google search doesn't find a way to force the mongdb `:` equality operator in case of null.  You could also enforce field creation in mongodb and keep using `"name": null`.  This might be a necessary consequence of switching from a relation database to a document store.

Comment: Yep, if I understood right. I could add. "name": {
   "type": "string",
   "required": true,
                        "default": null
  },

To the model defination. default as null

Answer (score -1):

You do not need the "where" when querying in MongoDB.

Can you try querying this instead?

> db.coll.find({fieldName: null})

Comment: Loopback has a different API to MongoDB. Queries are made though it's API and passed through to a connecting service to the database on the back end. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thats true. Loopback has a different api.